# Inverse characters in MPlayer + aalib

Tags: video, mplayer, ascii-art

I've noticed that the 'aalib' or 'aa' video output plugin for MPlayer does something it didn't do before: it uses inverse characters for display (black text over white background). I've tried several combinations of aalib options: noinverse , noreverse , nobold , noboldfont, but they don't work.
I'm not sure if the right syntax for passing arguments to the video output plugins is `-vo aa -aa:noinverse` or `-vo aa:noinverse`.
Anyone sucessfully passes arguments to mplayer plugins?